# How to use SQL Server in individual login ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am working on VS2015 preview and I am stuck somewhere with login.. Like in ASP.NET MVC VS2013 where we can login through SimpleMembershipInializer for e.g.

```
public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<LoginEntities>(null);

    try
    {
        using (var context = new LoginEntities())
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
            }
        }

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("LoginEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
    }
```

so I am doing in VS2015 like

```
 public class EBuilderUesr : IdentityUser<string, AspNetUserLogin, AspNetUserRole,AspNetUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<EBuilderUesr> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class AspNetUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string> { }
public class AspNetRole : IdentityRole<string, AspNetUserRole> { }
public class AspNetUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string> { }
public class AspNetUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string> { }
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUserLogin<string> { }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<EBuilderUesr, AspNetRole, string,AspNetUserLogin,AspNetUserRole,AspNetUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("BuilderTrackerEntities")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Now into IdentityConfig.cs is

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            //var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<EBuilderUesr>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<EBuilderUesr, AspNetRole, string, AspNetUserLogin, AspNetUserRole, AspNetUserClaim>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
}
```

getting error on above ApplicationUserManager..?

I have changed connection string in Config file also but still an getting error like..

[image: Error]

Please let me know. what I am going to wrong..?

Thank you,
_jitendra

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create your `UserManagerFactory` ?

Comment: var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<EBuilderUesr, AspNetRole, string, AspNetUserLogin, AspNetUserRole, AspNetUserClaim>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

Comment: this will give me error I am not sure where I am wrong.